# Is there a Python package that implements backtesting for VaR?

Tags: programming, backtesting, value-at-risk

I would like to use the tests of Christoffersen (1998), Engle and Manganelli (2004) or Kupiec (1995) to evaluate how good are the VaRs that I have projected. Is there a library that implements these tests?

Like the commands offered by the Risk Management Toolbox in MATALB (attached image).

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at riskfolio https://github.com/dcajasn/Riskfolio-Lib

Answer (score 1):

You can use **vartests** using the command:

```
`pip install vartests`
```

It contains Kupiec Test (1995), Christoffersen and Pelletier (2004) - Duration based independent test and Berkowitz tail test (2001).
The package is based on rugarch from R.